# Can Jenkins show the number of fail build \ succesful build?

Tags: android-studio, jenkins, gradle, jenkins-pipeline

I am working with android studio and got a task to use Jenkins pipeline in order to get the amount of successful or failed builds.
what I am searching for is a gradle script to enter my JenkinsFile in order to see these amount.
Some sort of a counter if that is even possible.

Would appreciate any sort of help, thank you!

Comment: You can try this plugin : https://plugins.jenkins.io/global-build-stats/

Comment: I cannot use plugins, I need to write it in a Jenkinsfile

Comment: It doesn't look straightforward without the plugin. You'll need to write a custom script which will 1) List out all the jobs 2) For all the jobs, get the status of each build 3) Store this data somewhere 4) Then export/represent.

Any restrictions for not able to use plugin?

Comment: I am looking for this exact script you are talking about ..

Comment: Yes, there is a restriction from my University.

Comment: @AngelAdir Did you write the script or how did you create the report?